# Difference between "probar" and "tratar", especially relating to food?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I was told that when trying/tasting food, you should use "pruébalo" and not "trátalo", but I don't understand the difference between the two. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Probar** is to *test*, while **tratar** is to *attempt*.  "Pruébalo" is telling someone to "test" it, or to taste it, while "Trátalo" is telling someone to attempt to do it.  Does this make sense, or is further clarification needed?

Comment: Thanks, makes slightly more sense. I think I was confused because that much clarity is not used in my everyday English, I usually use "try" for testing and attempting. Maybe because of that I kept thinking that tratar can be used for both (I learned that word before I learned probar).

Comment: Still confused though, what actions define an attempt? I would thought tasting some could be attempting to do something? I'm not seeing where the distinction would be

Comment: Probar is quite similar to "probe" in English, which can mean to investigate, gather more information, or test something. Tratar is  similar to the Spanish verb intentar, which is to try or attempt something (to have an intent to do something). You may or may not succeed at something you attempt (tratar), but you can't really fail when you try food (probar). Probar, to me, is more investigational, while tratar is more intention-based.

Comment: I'm still confused. I understand the usage of probar for investigate/gather more info but I don't get when you would use it for test something. For me, test this food or try this food mean the same thing. I also don't follow your logic of tratar being investigational and tratar being intentional. How is trying food not intentional?

Comment: Oliver, you can't always use English logic to understand Spanish.  A prime example is mañana has two meanings in Spanish - "tomorrow" and "morning", so one may say that he has a meeting "mañana en la mañana."  He's not saying he has a meeting "tomorrow in the tomorrow" nor "morning in the morning."  You need to accept that one word in English that has multiple meanings probably has multiple translation words in Spanish.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help and I accept that English logic is not always the same as Spanish logic, but at the same time I'm trying to figure what the Spanish logic actually is. In this case, I'm trying to figure under what circumstances probar would be used. From what I gathered it's when you try food and when you're testing something (an idea, an experiment). For tratar, I gather that it's used for trying to do something like "try to swim" or "try to say it this way". Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a fair summarization.  In the back of my mind, the words "test, try, prove" come to mind as the translation for "probar" if that helps differentiate the two words.

Comment: *Tratar* also means "treat", both as in "treating with respect" and as in "treating waste" or "treating disease".

Answer (score 1):

"Trátalo" does not mean "Try to do it." Instead, it means "Treat him," or even "Deal with it," as in: Trátalo bien (Treat him gently) or Trátalo en la próxima reunión (Deal with it -- some matter -- in next meeting). To say "Try to do it," or "Make a try/an attempt," you have to say "Inténtalo." However, you could use "Trata" to mean "Make a try." The pronoun "-lo" makes all the difference.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Spanish Language. Your answer is good. However, it should be more comprehensive. I would recommend you to providing usage examples so that even people with a low Spanish comprehension can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usage examples for *probar*:

- Meaning "try" as in "test", "sample", "check (out)":

  - *Tienes que probar esta receta.* = "You have to try this recipe."
  - *Pruebe nuestro nuevo servicio de envío a domicilio* = "Try our new home delivery service."
  - *¿Ya probaste apagándolo y volviéndolo a encender?* = "Did you already try turning it off and on again?"
- Meaning "prove", "demonstrate" (synonym: *comprobar*):

  - *Es inocente hasta que se pruebe lo contrario.* = "(S/H)e's innocent until proven otherwise."
  - *Pruebe que x < y para todo x > 1.* = "Prove that x < y for all x > 1."

Usage examples for *tratar*:

- Meaning "try" as in "attempt" (syn. *intentar*):

  - *Trataré de llegar temprano.* = "I'll try to arrive early."
  - *No trates de hacer esto en casa.* = "Don't try [to do] this at home."
- Meaning "treat":

  - *Los desechos no fueron tratados.* = "The waste products were not treated."
  - *Lo va a tratar un médico famoso.* = "A famous doctor is going to treat him."
  - *Me trataron con remedios naturales.* = "They treated me with natural medicines."
  - *Trátame con el debido respeto.* = "Treat me with due respect."

Note that *tratar* (as in "attempt") is usually employed in the pattern *tratar de* + infinitive, or else as an intransitive verb, while its synonym *intentar* is more like "attempt" in that it can take a noun as direct object. It can also be followed an infinitive or it can take a phrase with the preposition *con*:

- *No intenten esto en casa.* = "Don't try this at home."
- *Intenta verlo desde otro punto de vista.* = "Try seeing this from another point of view."
- *Voy a intentar con este otro.* = "I'm try with this other one."

In certain contexts *tratar* contrasts with *intentar* basically in that *tratar* suggests an effort to accomplish something, while *intentar* suggests just going for it. *Ni lo intentes.* = "Don't even try."

Answer (score 0):

"Tratar" is "To try"."Please at least try to come to my party", "Por favor al menos trata de venir a mi fiesta". 
It's to do something with an intention. It's also used with actions, so you use it with verbs. You don't use tratar with things (like foods).

(When you use "Tratar" on a person or on a thing means "to treat" like "Trátame con respeto" is "Treat me with respect", or "Por favor tratar con cuidado", "Please treat carefully")

"Probar" is 
"to try to do ", 
or "to taste " 
or "to test ".

Purpose of "probar" sometimes is not only to do something, but to gain knowledge about what happens when you do it, or what's you opinion about that action, or about that food. 
"Probá ese programa antes de enviarlo al cliente", "Test that programme before sending it to the client". You don't use it because you need it but because you have to check it works before you send it to a client.

"Probá esa masa, me parece que le falta sal", "Taste that dough I think it needs salt". I don't need you to eat it is just that I need your opinion.
"Probá vos, a mí no me funciona", "You try, but is not working for me". I need you to test something because I need to know your results.
"Probamos con un destornillador, pero no funcionó", "We tried by using a screwdriver, but didn't work". We have a problem, we're trying possible solutions.
"Probá con el segundo si el primero no funciona", "Try the second one if first doesn't work" We have alternatives, so let's try another one.

Hope it helps, I'm from Argentina, Spanish is my first language :)